# How to aggregate numbers within a range in PHP

Tags: php, for-loop

I have an array with numbers ranging from 1-150. I want to count the numbers that fall within the range 1-50, 51-100 and 101-150. I am not sure why I am struggling with this because it should be easy to do.

```
$test = ["12", "56", "123", "34", "67", "108", "29"];
```

Desired output

```
$final_array = 
    Array 
    ( 
        [start] => 1 [end] => 50 [count] => 3
        [start] => 51 [end] => 100 [count] => 2
        [start] => 101 [end] => 150 [count] => 2
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work,

```
        $test = array("12", "56", "123", "34", "67", "108", "29");
    $final_array    =   array(
        array('start' => 1 , 'end' => 50 , 'count' => 0),
        array('start' => 51 , 'end' => 100 , 'count' => 0),
        array('start' => 101 , 'end' => 150 , 'count' => 0),
    );
    for ($i=0;$i<count($test);$i++){
        if (($test[$i] > 0)&& ($test[$i] <= 50)){
            $final_array[0]['count']    =   $final_array[0]['count']+1;
        }else if($test[$i] > 50 && $test[$i] <= 100){
            $final_array[1]['count']    =   $final_array[1]['count']+1;
        }else if($test[$i] > 100 && $test[$i] <= 150){
            $final_array[2]['count']    =   $final_array[2]['count']+1;
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($final_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$final_array = array('range1' => 0, 'range2' => 0, 'range3' => 0);

foreach($test as $t){
    if($t>=1 and $t<=50)
        $final_array['range1']++;
    elseif($t>=51 and $t<=100)
        $final_array['range2']++;
    elseif($t>=101 and $t<=150)
        $final_array['range3']++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$final_array    =   array(
    array('start' => 1 , 'end' => 50 , 'count' => 0),
    array('start' => 51 , 'end' => 100 , 'count' => 0),
    array('start' => 101 , 'end' => 150 , 'count' => 0),
);

for ($i=0;$i<count($test);$i++){
    if ($test[$i] > 0 && $test[$i] <= 50){
        $final_array[0]['count']    =   $final_array[0]['count']++;
    }else if($test[$i] > 50 && $test[$i] <= 100){
        $final_array[1]['count']    =   $final_array[1]['count']++;
    }else if($test[$i] > 100 && $test[$i] <= 150){
        $final_array[2]['count']    =   $final_array[2]['count']++;
    }else{

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$test = array("12", "56", "123", "34", "67", "108", "29");

    $count1 = 0;$count2 = 0;$count3 = 0;
foreach($test as $t){    
    if($t > 0 && $t <= 50 ){ $count1 ++;
    }else if($t>50 && $t <=100){ $count2 ++;
    }else{ $count3 ++; }    
}
echo $count1.' - '.$count2.' - '.$count3;
```

Answer (score 0):

About as efficient as I could do quickly.

```
  $test = array(0,12,56,123,34,67,108,29,151);

  foreach($test as $val){
    if ($val == 0){continue;}
    elseif ($val < 51){$count1++;}
    elseif($val < 101){$count2++;}
    elseif($val < 151){$count3++;}
  }
  $final_array =array( 
  array('start' => 1,'end' => 50 ,'count' => $count1),
  array('start' => 51,'end' => 100 ,'count' => $count2),
  array('start' => 101,'end' => 150 ,'count' => $count3));
```

**RESULT:**

```
Array([0] => Array([start] => 1,  [end] => 50, [count] => 3)
      [1] => Array([start] => 51, [end] => 100,[count] => 2)
      [2] => Array([start] => 101,[end] => 150,[count] => 2)  
 )
```

I prefer `< 51` over `<=50` while the compiler will likely create the same machine code for each, it might use a more complex equation.  code looks cleaner.

When using a `elseif` and starting with the lower values to higher there is no reason to test the values twice.

In the following algorithm the `$val>=51 &&` is unnecessary.

```
if($val>=1 && $val<=50){$count1++;}
elseif($val>=51 && $val<=100){$count2++;}
```

This is more efficient:

```
if($val>0) and $val<51){$count1++;}
elseif($val<101){$count2++;}
```

An integer operator `($count)` is faster than
 
an array `$final_array[0]['count']`, especially an associative array, so I create the array after getting the count values.

An increment is more efficient

```
$final_array[0]['count']++;
```

than addition:

```
$final_array[0]['count']    =   $final_array[0]['count']+1;
```